# symfony 2 upload one up bundle

Tags: symfony, file-upload, upload, event-handling, oneupuploaderbundle

I use the OneUp bundle for symfony 2,  method's listener class is never call

```
//service.yml
amd_picture.uploadListener:
    class: Amd\PictureBundle\Services\UploadListener
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tag:
      - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_chunk_upload, method: onUpload}
```

the listener class implements the onUpload method and the corresponding event , is it the rigth event to listen ???

```
class UploadListener {

   private $doctrine;

   public function __construct($doctrine) {
      $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
   }

   public function onUpload(PostChunkUploadEvent $event) {
       //source code
   }
}
```

the srcipt for the front end template

```
<script>
  YUI().use('uploader', function(Y) {

    var uploader = new Y.Uploader(
            {
                multipleFiles: true,
                uploadURL: "{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}",
                width: "300px",
                height: "60px"

            }).render("#fileupload");
</script>
```

i don't find why the onUpload method is never call?

Comment: Having the same problem, in XML it seems to work though

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the postPersitentEvent in you use statement:

```
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
```

Answer (score 2):

Small correction:

```
//service.yml
amd_picture.uploadListener:
   class: Amd\PictureBundle\Services\UploadListener
   arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
      tag:
        - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist, method:     onUpload}
```

Is not tag. Is:

```
tags:
        - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist, method:     onUpload}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [YUI3-Uploader](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/) is not able to split files into chunks, therefore the [YUI3Controller](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Controller/YUI3Controller.php) of the [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle) does not support it either. This means there is no `post_chunk_upload` which will be dispatched and your `EventListener` is never called.

If you want to process your file after it is uploaded successfully, try listen to the `PostPersistEvent` like described in the [bundles manual](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/custom_logic.md).

```
//service.yml
amd_picture.uploadListener:
    class: Amd\PictureBundle\Services\UploadListener
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tag:
        - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_persist, method:     onUpload}
```

And be sure to pass a `PostPersistEvent` object to the listener.

```
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;

class UploadListener {
    public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have replace the ChunkEvent by a PostPersistEvent (in my service.yml and controller with the use statement), but nothing happen when i upload file.

Comment: Does the file itself gets uploaded to the configured directory?

Comment: yes  the file is uploaded in the configured directory but nothing happend

Comment: ok finally i use the orphanage mode, i follow your instructions but i don't arrive to catch the postPersist event, but with orphanage it's works fine for me, thx for you help

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me. I've created an issue on GitHub, and will double check that as soon as possible. https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/issues/75

Comment: have you check this ? i would like to know the result  i see nothing on Github, other people have the same result ?

Comment: I've tested this with the following files: https://gist.github.com/sheeep/7970759. The UploadListener gets called and the files uploaded.